# Java OpenGL - Apply different color per side of glutSolidCube

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, glut, jogl

For my Java OpenGL project I am trying to make a Rubik's Cube.
I've got all rotations calculated and working, but there's one thing I don't know how to do, namely give each side of the cube it's own color.
I used glRotatef and glTranslatef to position each of the 27 blocks, and glutSolidCube to draw each block.
How can I give each side of glutSolidCube a different color?
I've looked at textured cubes, but that seems hard as I don't know the (x, y, z) coordinates of each block, I only have the transformation matrix (rotation and translation).
What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be possible directly: `glutSolidCube` does not generate color attributes (see the `fghCube` function in [freeglut source code](http://sourceforge.net/p/freeglut/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/freeglut/freeglut/src/fg_geometry.c)).

The simplest way would be to generate the geometry of the cube yourself. Generate 6 (faces) * 4 = 24 vertices total, with the expected positions, normals and an additional color attribute per vertex. Just like for the normal attribute, for each of the 8 distinct vertex positions on a cube, you should have 3 different colors (since the same vertex is shared by 3 faces but you need a different color per face).

Another way if you really insist on using `glutSolidCube` would be to assign the vertex color based on the vertex normal in the vertex shader. But maybe you are not using vertex shaders...